# Indexing error with an empty sublist

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tree

I am trying to implement a tree data structure. One of the methods in my tree object associates nodes with coordinates whilst mapping the children to the parent nodes & vice-verse.

Initially I gave each node a list of children which turned out to be incorrect. So to remedy that I decided to just initialize nodes with an empty list and that's where the trouble started.

First the code that works...

```
    def treeSetUp(self):

        '''Set tree's initial structure
        For each level in treeArray
        [level, leaf, [node number, parent, full, [coordinates], [centroid], [children]], [node number, leaf, full, [coordinates], [centroid], [children]], ...]'''


        # Create root level & node    
        leaf = False    
        numChildren = (self.dims[0] * self.dims[1] * self.dims[2])/self.diameters[0]**3 # This maybe whay it only works for cubes
        children = [(kids) for kids in xrange(numChildren)]
        rootCoords = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, self.dims[0], 0], [self.dims[0], 0, 0], [self.dims[0], self.dims[1], 0], [0, 0, self.dims[2]], [0, self.dims[1], self.dims[2]], [self.dims[0], 0, self.dims[2]], [self.dims[0], self.dims[1], self.dims[2]]])
        xCentroid = np.sum(rootCoords[:,0])/8.0
        yCentroid = np.sum(rootCoords[:,1])/8.0
        zCentroid = np.sum(rootCoords[:,2])/8.0
        rootCentroids = [xCentroid, yCentroid, zCentroid]
        rootNode = [0, None, False, rootCoords, rootCentroids, copy.copy(children)]

        treeArray = []
        treeArray.append([0, leaf, [rootNode]])
        allCoordinates = []
        allCoordinates.append(rootCoords)
        allCentroids = []
        allCentroids.append(rootCentroids)

        for idx in xrange(self.depth):

            # self.coordGenerator splits a given domain into cubes & returns the
            # coordinates of each cube as well as its associated centroid
            # This is done at different resolutions at different levels
            levelCoordinates, levelCentroid = self.coordGenerator(idx+1)
            allCoordinates.append(levelCoordinates)
            allCentroids.append(levelCentroid)

            nodeCount = 0            
            if idx == self.depth-1:
                leaf = True 

            # Generate level's nodes            
            newNodes = []
            for parentNode, node in enumerate(treeArray[idx][2]):

                # Generate nodes's child list                
                children = []
                for nodeNumber, child in enumerate(node[5]):

                    # Gereate child list                    
                    if leaf:
                        children = [None]
                    else:
                        numChildren = (self.diameters[idx]**3)/(self.diameters[idx+1]**3)
                        children = [(kids + nodeCount*numChildren) for kids in xrange(numChildren)]

                    # Assign coordinates to level 1 nodes else generate placeholders      
                    if idx == 0:
                        nodeCoords = levelCoordinates[nodeNumber]
                        nodeCentroid = levelCentroid[nodeNumber]
                    else:
                        nodeCoords = []
                        nodeCentroid = []

                    newNodes.append([nodeCount, parentNode, False, copy.deepcopy(nodeCoords), copy.deepcopy(nodeCentroid), copy.copy(children)])
                    nodeCount += 1

            newLevel = [idx+1, leaf, copy.deepcopy(newNodes)]
            treeArray.append(newLevel)

        # Operation find parents
        for level in xrange(1, self.depth):
            for childNode, centroid in enumerate(allCentroids[level+1]):

                for node in treeArray[level][2]:

                    # bounding box of parent node
                    boundary = node[3]
                    xBound = [np.min(boundary[:,0]), np.max(boundary[:,0])]
                    yBound = [np.min(boundary[:,1]), np.max(boundary[:,1])]
                    zBound = [np.min(boundary[:,2]), np.max(boundary[:,2])]

                    # Is child's centroid in parents ounding box?
                    if (xBound[0] <= centroid[0] <= xBound[1]) and (yBound[0] <= centroid[1] <= yBound[1]) and (zBound[0] <= centroid[2] <= zBound[1]):
                        treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][1] = node[0]       # Add parent node to child
                        treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][3] = allCoordinates[level+1][childNode]
                        treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][4] = centroid
#                        treeArray[level][2][node[0]][5].append(childNode)   # Add child to parents list of children
                        break
```

And now the code that doesnt...

```
   def treeSetUp(self):

        '''Set tree's initial structure
        For each level in treeArray
        [level, leaf, [node number, parent, full, [coordinates], [centroid], [children]], [node number, leaf, full, [coordinates], [centroid], [children]], ...]'''


        # Create root level & node    
        leaf = False    
        numChildren = (self.dims[0] * self.dims[1] * self.dims[2])/self.diameters[0]**3 # This maybe whay it only works for cubes
        children = [(kids) for kids in xrange(numChildren)]
        rootCoords = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, self.dims[0], 0], [self.dims[0], 0, 0], [self.dims[0], self.dims[1], 0], [0, 0, self.dims[2]], [0, self.dims[1], self.dims[2]], [self.dims[0], 0, self.dims[2]], [self.dims[0], self.dims[1], self.dims[2]]])
        xCentroid = np.sum(rootCoords[:,0])/8.0
        yCentroid = np.sum(rootCoords[:,1])/8.0
        zCentroid = np.sum(rootCoords[:,2])/8.0
        rootCentroids = [xCentroid, yCentroid, zCentroid]
        rootNode = [0, None, False, rootCoords, rootCentroids, copy.copy(children)]

        treeArray = []
        treeArray.append([0, leaf, [rootNode]])
        allCoordinates = []
        allCoordinates.append(rootCoords)
        allCentroids = []
        allCentroids.append(rootCentroids)

        for idx in xrange(self.depth):

            # self.coordGenerator splits a given domain into cubes & returns the
            # coordinates of each cube as well as its associated centroid
            # This is done at different resolutions at different levels
            levelCoordinates, levelCentroid = self.coordGenerator(idx+1)
            allCoordinates.append(levelCoordinates)
            allCentroids.append(levelCentroid)

            nodeCount = 0            
            if idx == self.depth-1:
                leaf = True  

            # Generate level's nodes            
            newNodes = []
            for parentNode, node in enumerate(treeArray[idx][2]):

                # Generate nodes's child list                
                children = []
                for nodeNumber, child in enumerate(node[5]):

                    # Gereate child list                    
                    if leaf:
                        children = [None]
                    else:
                        numChildren = (self.diameters[idx]**3)/(self.diameters[idx+1]**3)
                        children = [(kids + nodeCount*numChildren) for kids in xrange(numChildren)]

                    # Assign coordinates to level 1 nodes else generate placeholders      
                    if idx == 0:
                        nodeCoords = levelCoordinates[nodeNumber]
                        nodeCentroid = levelCentroid[nodeNumber]
                    else:
                        nodeCoords = []
                        nodeCentroid = []

                    newNodes.append([nodeCount, parentNode, False, copy.deepcopy(nodeCoords), copy.deepcopy(nodeCentroid), []]) #copy.copy(children)])
                    nodeCount += 1

            newLevel = [idx+1, leaf, copy.deepcopy(newNodes)]
            treeArray.append(newLevel)

        # Operation find parents
        for level in xrange(1, self.depth):
            for childNode, centroid in enumerate(allCentroids[level+1]):

                for node in treeArray[level][2]:

                    # bounding box of parent node
                    boundary = node[3]
                    xBound = [np.min(boundary[:,0]), np.max(boundary[:,0])]
                    yBound = [np.min(boundary[:,1]), np.max(boundary[:,1])]
                    zBound = [np.min(boundary[:,2]), np.max(boundary[:,2])]

                    # Is child's centroid in parents ounding box?
                    if (xBound[0] <= centroid[0] <= xBound[1]) and (yBound[0] <= centroid[1] <= yBound[1]) and (zBound[0] <= centroid[2] <= zBound[1]):
                        treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][1] = node[0]       # Add parent node to child
                        treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][3] = allCoordinates[level+1][childNode]
                        treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][4] = centroid
#                        treeArray[level][2][node[0]][5].append(childNode)   # Add child to parents list of children
                        break
```

The only difference being that instead of supplying the erroneous list of child nodes, I supplied an empty list.

The error it gives..

> ```
> treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][1] = node[0]       # Add parent node to child IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

So why would adding an empty list instead of an occupied list change indexing?

I dont have the privilege to share the rest of the code unfortunately, I have tried to replicate this error in a simplified code but so far no luck.

I suspect that there is something obvious here but after a day of staring at it with incredulity, well its making less sense.

Comment: I think you need to realise that you've made it difficult for someone to help you here.  You've provided some complicated code which nobody else can run as it relies on functions and data you have decided not to share with us.  If you really want an answer it would be better to provide a complete program that others can run to reproduce your problem.  Slapping a bounty on the question makes it no more likely that anyone *will* help you because you've made it no more likely that anyone *can* help you.

Comment: @LukeWoodward That's a fair point but I was wondering if there was a conceptual reason why an empty list would be different from a list with elements in it & why that would effect the process of indexing?

Comment: There is no way you are going to index an empty list, where do you add data to those empty lists before you try to index

Comment: An empty list has nothing to index. This is sort of like asking if having a book with no pages in it affects the numbering of the pages, there's no contents to index, so asking Python for index 0 is asking for something nonexistent.

Comment: So if I have a list of empty lists  are you saying I cant use indexing to access one of those empty lists? I ask because I can do the following with no problem `myList = [[],[],[]]
myList[2].append(2)
print myList`

Comment: @DrBwts, you can, but you are either trying to index an empty inner list or index myList before you have added any sublists

Comment: Just post the inputs the working and the erroneous. If `children` is a list of tuples `children = [(kids) for kids in xrange(numChildren)]` is wrong. Single element tuple is `(kids,)`. And `for level in xrange(1, self.depth)` here `level` starts with 1 and you index with `level+1`, might be wrong.

Comment: This is misconception that you'll need to fully understand before moving on with python. As others have said, and empty list can't be indexed, cause there are no elements to be accessed. Try `x = []; x[0]` and you'll get `IndexError: list index out of range`. On the other hand, `x = [[]]; x[0]` will work (should return `[]`). Remember, everything in python is an object. So, in the second case, the outer list contains an object--which happens to be en empty list--, so you can access it. But in the first case, you are trying to access something where there's nothing. Does it make sense?

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here about what I am asking. I am not trying to index anything **within** the empty list. The code is accessing a list of lists & when one of those lists is empty, I get an indexing error when trying to access the contents of one of the other lists which has elements & is not empty

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the right hand side of that line indeed has elements & is not empty.  However, the left hand side refers to the element `[1]` of a list.  If that element is not already present in your list, you'll get the error.  This is why I've asked what `treeArray[level+1][2][childNode]` is immediately before the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you print

`treeArray[level+1][2][childNode]`

right before the line where the error occurs, you will find that it is `[]` in the code that doesn't work and equal to something else in the code that does work.  So when you set `...[childNode][1]` to have a value, you're running into the same error you would if you had

```
a = []
a[1]=1
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Whereas in the working code you're seeing something like:

```
a=[4,6]
a[1]=1
print a
>[4,1]
```

When you don't send it an empty list, but rather a copy of a child, then when it tries to set that entry, it is successful because that entry is already in the list, it's just changing the value.  On the other hand if it's trying to set the [1] entry of an empty list, then it's going to fail because the list entry doesn't exist yet. Think of `a[n]=x` as being like filing the legal forms required to change the identity of `a[n]`.  The process does not work if you file the forms for a person who does not exist.  To actually create `a[n]` requires some other processes to happen.

You should simplify the code significantly. Rather than having lists of things like: `[nodeCount, parentNode, False, copy.deepcopy(nodeCoords), copy.deepcopy(nodeCentroid), []]`, I think you'll be better off defining an object that contains all of this.  It will be easier to debug.

Comment: The original iteration of the code made use of objects instead of lists but unfortunately this led to memory issues when implemented with large data structures.

Comment: okay.  Fair enough.  Can you check if my hypothesis is right about `treeArray[level+1][2][childNode]`?

Comment: thanks I ran through what you suggested but that is not the issue. I'm not trying to access the `childNode` list.

Comment: So what is `treeArray[level+1][2][childNode]` right before the error?  I need to know this to be able to make sense of the error.

Comment: "I'm not trying to access the `childNode` list."  But you've got `treeArray[level+1][2][childNode][1]=...` which to me looks like you're trying to assign a value to its `[1]` entry.  If it's currently empty then it doesn't know where to put that value.

Comment: sorry for the delay getting back to you on this (have had a nice long break from work). Yes you were right the list was empty & I could not actually change an empty value. I owe you +25, I'll try & make that up for you some how.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  Glad if it helped.